# Injecting EJB Bean using CDI

Tags: jakarta-ee, jboss, ejb, jboss7.x, cdi

I'm trying to inject a EJB singleton bean into a CDI bean using @Inject. But the injected instance is sometime local and sometime it's remote instance (changes over restart). It's not consistent.

In the following sample, the TestService ejb's remote instance is injected into the GetTestData cdi managed bean. But I'm expecting the local instance. And it's also not consistent, sometimes it injects the local instance. I've figured out that by printing the injected bean in GetTestData class.

As a note, my test classes are excluded in the deployment package.

Any idea how to make it consistently inject local instance?

**EJB Singleton Bean:**

```
@Singleton
@Local(TestService.class)
@Remote(TestServiceRemote.class)
public class TestServiceImpl implements TestService {
    ..
}
```

**CDI Bean:**

```
public class GetTestData {

    @Inject
    TestService testService;

    ....
}
```

**Unit Test:**

```
@RunWith(CdiRunner.class)
public class GetTestDataTest {

    @Inject
    private GetTestData getTestData;

    @Produces
    @ProducesAlternative
    @Mock
    private TestService testService;

    .....
}
```

I'm using **JBoss 7.1.1-Final** version (Application Server) and the Weld core version is **1.1.23-Final**.

I'm not able to use @EJB because I'm using cdi-unit for testing.

Comment: Your question needs clarifications. What is your targeted server and version? What is JBoss 1.1.1-Final? Can you share your test, EJB and its interfaces?

Comment: Antoine, Added sample code to improve the clarity and also answered the your questions.

Answer (score 4):

First, keep in mind that CDI injection doesn't support remote EJB out of the box (thru `@Inject` annotation). When using an EJB as a CDI bean, it's remote interface is excluded from the set of type for the bean as stated [here](http://docs.jboss.org/cdi/spec/1.2/cdi-spec.html#session_bean_types).
To be able to use a remote EJB you'll have to declare it as a [resource](http://docs.jboss.org/cdi/spec/1.2/cdi-spec.html#resources) like this.

```
public class ResourceProducers {

@Produces @EJB(ejbLink="../their.jar#TestServiceRemote")
TestServiceRemote remoteService;

}
```

So the behaviour you're experiencing probably comes from a CDI-unit since it is impossible that CDI use a remote EJB interface in an injection point.

My advice:

1. Ask yourself if you really need EJB remote in your application. Today with JAX-RS and other techno like websocket they are a bit old fashioned.
2. If you don't need EJB remote, add the [EJB support](http://jglue.org/cdi-unit-user-guide/#ejb) annotation to your CDI-Unit test, it'll probably help the framework to give you the expected EJB behaviour (singleton). Also don't mock the EJB like you did : I don't think CDI-Unit will replicate EJB nature in your mock.
3. If you want to stick with EJB remote, I guess you'll have to switch to a more strong test framework like [Arquillian](http://arquillian.org/). I'm not a CDI-Unit specialist but I don't think they support remote EJB.
4. If you're starting a development, you really should consider using [WildFly](http://wildfly.org/) application server, the next generation of JBoss server. You'll get Java EE 7 and more robust server.

Comment: What i really wanted is the local view of the ejb in GetTestData and not the remote one. But what I'm getting is the remote view of the ejb. And my cdi-unit test classes are excluded in the deployment.

Comment: As I wrote CDI-unit doesn't support EJB out of the box and probably not remote EJB. So you're experiencing random behaviour. If you really want to test remote EJB you'll have to use Arquillian with EJB container like JBoss AS 7.1.1.

Comment: Ignore the unit test, but I'm getting this random behaviour of weld injection in the runtime.

Comment: Sorry I don't understand. It's totally impossible with the code you put in your example. `@Inject` cannot inject a remote EJB unless you have a producer somewhere. Could you give the real code with interface definition and right annotation.

Comment: It doesn't have any producer for that ejb remote view. Jboss cdi container (weld) takes care of injecting that ejb bean into my cdi bean. I'm facing this issue in our enterprise application and so i can't put that real code out here.

Comment: Sorry. It's very hard to help if you don't provide a use case to reproduce your bug. The only idea I can give would ce to test your application with JBoss EAP 6.3. You can download it and use for dev freely. AS 7.1.1 is quite old and contains a lot of bugs.